# cv2 Python image blending "Fade" transition

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision

I am using cv2 for Python. I am pretty close to creating a "blending fade" transition between two images, but im not getting the results I hope for.

What I want to do is as my `fadein` variable counts up, i am passing it to the `cv2.addWeighted` function to create a blend that changes as my `fadein` variable changes.

so, summed up...a cinema cross fade effect. Whats happening is the `fadein` variable counts, and when it reaches its max range, the image jumps to the next one.

[EDIT] 
my problem is the cv objects are not simultaneously running with my dynamic `fadein` variable.

```
def fadeIn (img1, img2): #pass images here to fade between
        while True:
                for FADEIN in range(0,10):
                        fadein = FADEIN/10.0
                        fadeout=1.0
                        fadeout -= 0.1
                        dst = cv2.addWeighted( img1, fadeout, img2, fadein, -1)#linear $
                        cv2.imshow('window', dst)
                        print fadein
                        time.sleep(0.05);
                        if fadein == 1.0: #blendmode mover
                                fadein = 1.0
                return # exit function

while True:
  if Position == 55:
  fadeIn(dog, panda)
```

Answer (score 3):

Your code is also missing the inverse (1-fadein) for the cross fade. I also added a dynamic length setting.

```
def fadeIn (img1, img2, len=10): #pass images here to fade between
    while True:
        for IN in range(0,len):
            fadein = IN/float(len)
            dst = cv2.addWeighted( img1, 1-fadein, img2, fadein, 0)
            cv2.imshow('window', dst)
            cv2.waitKey(1)
            print fadein
```

Answer (score 1):

Ah, I was missing `cv2.waitKey(1)`

My revised 'blending' transition between images function:

```
def fadeIn (img1, img2): #pass images here to fade between
        #while True:
        for IN in range(0,10):
                fadein = IN/10.0
                dst = cv2.addWeighted( img1, fadein, img2, fadein, 0)#linear $
                cv2.imshow('window', dst)
                cv2.waitKey(1)
                print fadein
                time.sleep(0.05)
                if fadein == 1.0: #blendmode mover
                        fadein = 1.0
        return # exit function
```